# Render PDF from ISML and retrieve binary data

Tags: intershop

our REST-API should deliver a PDF based on an HTML template.

Our intention is to generate the HTML using ISML, stuff it into the  PDF processor and grab the output for the REST response.

What is the best way to implement that with Intershop 7.9?

Answer (score 3):

Rendering the PDF is easy to accomplish using the Intershop PDF creation documentation.

Getting the HTML from an ISML template is more tricky, mostly because of missing examples. But in the ISH code there are two example classes hidden:

```
PageEntryPoint2PDFInteractionProcessor:TemplateCallable
MailMgrImpl:MailTemplateCallable
```

Both can grab HTML from ISML coming from two different places.

```
    LocaleMgr localeMgr = NamingMgr.getManager(LocaleMgr.class);
    String webpageContent = "";

    // put some demo stuff into the PD
    PipelineDictionary dict = new PipelineDictionaryImpl();
    dict.put("foo", "foo");

    Request request = Request.getCurrent();

    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
    try {
        // demo code, you might want to use another template than Empty.isml
        TemplateCallable callable = new TemplateCallable("Empty", localeMgr,
                        dict, request);
        Future<ServletResponse> future = executorService.submit(callable);
        ServletResponse fwResponse = future.get();
        webpageContent = fwResponse.getContent();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Logger.error(this, "Error while getting template render result.");
    }
```

The code for the `Callable`-Class you on can derive from the example classes I mentioned above.